# Remove empty array elements except first (empty)

Tags: php, arrays

Is possible to remove all empty elements from a array except the first element? Looking at this example:

#### Original

```
Array (
[0] => val1
[1] => val2
[2] => val3
[3] => 
[4] => val4
[5] => val5
[6] => val6
[7] => 
[8] => val7
[9] => val8
[10] => val9
)
```

#### Desired Result

```
Array (
[0] => val1
[1] => val2
[2] => val3
[3] => 
[4] => val4
[5] => val5
[6] => val6
[7] => val7
[8] => val8
[9] => val9
)
```

Is this possible? Which is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Create a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Of course you have tried a few things right? So show us a few!

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly i am not expert on PHP, i tried the basic, array_filter but of course it remove all the empty elements, do you have any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
$a = array(
    '0' => 'val1',
    '1' => 'val2',
    '2' => 'val3',
    '3' => '',
    '4' => 'val4',
    '5' => 'val5',
    '6' => 'val6',
    '7' => '',
    '8' => 'val7',
    '9' => 'val8',
    '10' => 'val9',
);
// special flag to check if empty 
// element already exists in new array
$has_empty = false;
$new_a = [];
foreach ($a as $el) {
    if (!empty($el) || !$has_empty) {
        $new_a[] = $el;
        if (empty($el)) {
            $has_empty = true;
        }
    }
}
echo'<pre>',print_r($new_a),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter`:

```
$first = false;
$result = array_filter($arr, function($k) use($first){
    if(empty($k) && !first){
       $first = true;
       return true;
    }
    return !empty($k);
})
```